# ¿Mahonesa o Mayonesa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, comida

Sé que son palabras que se refieren a lo mismo con la distinción de que *mahonesa* hace referencia a la "mayonesa" originaria de un pueblo de Menorca llamado Mahón

La pregunta es, ¿hay algún contexto o algún motivo por el que debiera utilizar un término por encima del otro o es indiferente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas palabras son correctas y aceptadas, si bien mahonesa es más correcta históricamente por proceder de la ciudad de Mahón.

En efecto, hay bastante unanimidad en cuanto al origen de esta receta: los franceses descubrieron que los lugareños de Mahón, Menorca (isla de España situada en el Mar Mediterráneo) hacían tal receta. Luego los franceses la popularizaron bajo el nombre de *mayonnaise*, de ahí que posteriormente se acabara difundiendo la versión con "y".

El DRAE menciona:

> [mayonesa](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=lOdObXkNQD6tFQceDk). ‘Salsa que se hace batiendo aceite y huevo’: «Nada más
>   que en la mayonesa se gastaron catorce huevos» (Skármeta Cartero
>   [Chile 1986]). Es igualmente válida la forma mahonesa, más cercana a
>   la etimología (de Mahón, capital de la isla de Menorca), pero menos
>   frecuente en el uso: «¿Quién se resiste a esa punta de espárrago con
>   mahonesa?» (Marsillach Ático [Esp. 1995]). No debe usarse, con este
>   sentido, la voz bayonesa, que designa, en realidad, un tipo de dulce
>   (→ bayonesa).

Buscando en internet se encuentra bastante debate y referencias. En general, se indica como bastante válido el hecho de que esta receta fuera descubierta en Menorca por el hecho de que no hay referencias a esta receta en la cocina francesa hasta que estos ocuparon la isla (1756-1763).

Algunas referencias:

- Sobre el origen: [¿Quién inventó la salsa mahonesa (mayonesa)?](http://blogs.elpais.com/gastronotas-de-capel/2014/06/quien-invento-la-salsa-mahonesa-mayonesa.html)

> Aunque nadie ha demostrado de forma fehaciente que surgiera en
>   Menorca, varias hipótesis de peso sostienen que se conocía antes de la
>   llegada de los franceses. La más importante la aporta el libro Art de
>   la Cuina del franciscano Francesc Roger (Ciudadela), correspondiente a
>   la primera mitad del siglo XVIII, donde se reseñan 19 recetas en las
>   que interviene el l’aioli bo (alioli bueno), nombre que
>   presumiblemente el fraile daba a la salsa mahonesa. Pero como en
>   ninguna parte del manual se describe cómo se elaboraba, los defensores
>   de esta teoría, con Pelfort a la cabeza, suponen que era tan popular
>   que Fra Roger daba por hecho que la gente ya sabía cómo hacerla. Todo
>   es posible.
>
> (...)
>
> Todos los diccionarios etimológicos franceses afirman que el origen de
>   la palabra es menorquín

La [Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayonnaise#Anecdotal_origins) menciona:

> One of the most common places named as the origin of mayonnaise is the
>   town of Mahón in Menorca, Spain, where it was then taken to France
>   after Armand de Vignerot du Plessis's victory over the British at the
>   city's port in 1756. According to this version, the sauce was
>   originally known as salsa mayonesa in Spanish and maonesa (later
>   maionesa) in Catalan (as it is still known in Menorca), later becoming
>   mayonnaise as it was popularized by the French.

Y luego me gusta este comentario en la noticia [¿Mahonesa, mayonesa o bayonesa?](http://www.heraldo.es/noticias/ocio_cultura/cultura/2013/11/12/mahonesa_mayonesa_bayonesa_256747_308.html):

> (...) La mayonesa o mahonesa es una salsa emulsionada fría elaborada
>   principalmente a base de huevo entero y aceite vegetal batidos. De
>   ORIGEN ESPAÑOL, CONCRETAMENTE MENORQUÍN, generalmente se la sazona con
>   sal, zumo de limón o vinagre. Se trata de una salsa de origen español
>   emparentada culinariamente con el alioli.
>
> Tras la conquista de Mahón, la salsa aparece en Francia. La cocina con
>   aceite es extraña a la gastronomía francesa (con excepción de la
>   Provence) y una salsa que emplea aceite en una gran proporción resulta
>   desagradable a paladares no acostumbrados. No es de extrañar que NO
>   aparezca tal salsa en los textos culinarios franceses del siglo XVIII.
>
> La primera referencia de 1804 menciona la palabra mayonnaise. Ya en
>   1806 las menciones a la salsa son abundantes. Marie-Antoine Carême
>   (1783-1833) gran recopilador de recetas menciona en su capítulo X la
>   "Sauce Magnonaise" (del verbo magner o manier que significa manipular)
>   de la que representa cinco variaciones distintas. Prosper Montagné
>   emplea el nombre moyennaise (o moyeunaise), o moyen (o moyeu) que
>   significaba "yema" en antiguo francés.
>
> El libro anónimo La Cuisinière Bourgeoise de 1786 —publicado, por
>   tanto, a los treinta años de la caída de Mahón en manos de Richelieu—,
>   no se habla aún de la salsa, lo que permite suponer que todavía no era
>   muy conocida.
>
> Existen otras teorías sobre la etimología, algunas más pintorescas que
>   otras. Bayonnaise, de Bayona en Francia; magnonnaise, de magnier,
>   manier, manejar; mayennaise, en honor del duque Mayenne o de la
>   comarca francesa del mismo nombre; moyeunnaise, de moyeu, yema de
>   huevo en francés antiguo, y quizás alguna más. (...)

He mirado en el distintos diccionarios (normales y etimológicos) franceses y parece que se confirma el origen, o al menos se confirma que la suposición más general es la que habla del origen menorquín:

- La [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mayonnaise/49989?q=mayonnaise):

> nom féminin
>
> (peut-être de Port Mahón, nom propre)

- El [Littre](http://www.littre.org/definition/mayonnaise):

> Quelques auteurs conseillent de préférer mahonnaise, attendu que le
>   nom de cette sauce vient, disent-ils, de celui de **Mahon**, ville que
>   Richelieu prit, LEGOARANT. Le Cuisinier de la ville et de la campagne
>   écrit magnonaise.

- El [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mayonnaise):

> Étymol. et Hist. 1806 saumon à la mayonnaise (Viard, Le Cuisinier
>   impérial, Paris, Bordas, p.342); 1855 sauce mayonnaise, mayonnaise de
>   volaille (Audot, Cuisin. campagne et ville, p.47 et 132). **Peut-être
>   tiré du nom de (Port) Mahon, capitale de Minorque**, en souvenir de la
>   prise de cette ville par le Duc de Richelieu en 1756, bien que la
>   1redate d'apparition du mot soit très postérieure à celle de
>   l'événement; aussi Bescherelle y voit plutôt une orthographe vicieuse
>   de bayonnaise* (v. FEW t.6, 1, p.52).